# Angular open different component on modal

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I have an Angular app shell architecture with different components. The idea is when I am on a component and I click on a button, a new modal opens that contains a different component from another repository. I was looking for a proper way using the bootstrap modal, either by adding the URL or by loading it somehow but I cannot find a way to load eventually the component in the modal. I found some suggestions like iframe, but what I had in mind was something like

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(components['exampleComponent']);
```

Is it somehow possible, or should I try a different approach?

Comment: what do you mean by ".. a different component from another repository"? As in a version control repository like Github?

Comment: yes, I apologize, I meant a component in a different project.

Comment: Hmm as far as I'm aware, I don't think that can be done since Angular will need the components locally in order to build and compile the code into its static output files. Maybe ask the repo owner if you can use some of the code in your own project?

Comment: Is it possible to be done by using the URL?